# Disposing a base class when Derived have no resources of its own to Dispose

Tags: c#

I've seen many answers showing how to implement `Dispose` on both Base and Derived (ie like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27920483/460084)).

I am however not sure about the case where I'm deriving from `Base` which implements `IDisposed` but my `Derived` have *no* resources of it's own that need disposing.

In this scenario do I still need to override `Dispose` at all ?

Comment: If you derived class don't hold resources which need explicit calls to dispose then no need to override `Dispose()`.

Comment: thanks @LeVu can you write an answer please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no you don't need to. It will call the `Dispose` of the base class, and that all you need.

Comment: I assume I still need to do 'using (derived) { ... }` ?

Comment: @kofifus You should always properly dispose the object by using the `using` keyword or calling the `Dispose` method when the object is no longer needed.